# How do I sum this pivot table but retain my time row?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my csv pivot table, and it has 2 sets of data, hence the duplicate items in the 'pct_type' column.  I want to all the values so that I'll be left with just the 6 ranges in the first column, and also the time row. So there will be just 2's in the second column, '9:30', and the rest will also be added.

GROUPBY SUM DOES NOT WORK
[image: csv]

Comment: Have you tried something like `df.groupby('pct_type').sum()`?

Comment: @VivekJain no that doesn't work

Comment: Can you explain what result your get with groupby and sum, and how it differs from what you want? Please show your attempts, so others can see the issues and build on your work, or maybe point out any errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask